# Invalid read of size 8, but no memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, apache-kafka

I am doing C++ Kafka Client https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.cpp.

In my KafkaProducer class, there are several pointers.

```
RdKafka::Conf* m_conf;
RdKafka::Conf* m_tconf;
RdKafka::Producer* m_producer;
RdKafka::Topic* m_topic;

m_conf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_GLOBAL);
m_producer = RdKafka::Producer::create(m_conf, m_errstr);
m_tconf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_TOPIC);
m_topic = RdKafka::Topic::create(m_producer, m_topic_str, m_tconf, m_errstr);
```

In the destructor, I did the following:

```
if(m_producer)
    delete m_producer;

if(m_topic)
    delete m_topic;

if(m_tconf)
    delete m_tconf;

if(m_conf)
    delete m_conf;
```

I used valgrind to check my program, there is no leaks. But there are some problems of "Invalid read". **Some memory are freed twice. But I have do idea which memory.** The following are part of the valgrind output.

```
==4627== 2 errors in context 10 of 12:
==4627== Invalid read of size 8
==4627==    at 0x52887A7: RdKafka::log_cb_trampoline(rd_kafka_s const*, int, char const*, char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka++.so.1)
==4627==    by 0x5493C8F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.so.1)
==4627==    by 0x549A531: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.so.1)
==4627==    by 0x54A0219: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.so.1)
==4627==    by 0x54A1A13: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librdkafka.so.1)
==4627==    by 0x506C181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==4627==    by 0x5EE747C: clone (clone.S:111)
==4627==  Address 0x68df7f8 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 64 free'd
==4627==    at 0x4C2C2BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4627==    by 0x407E90: KafkaProducer::disconnect() (kafkaproducer.cpp:57)
==4627==    by 0x407D29: KafkaProducer::~KafkaProducer() (kafkaproducer.cpp:32)
==4627==    by 0x407DF1: KafkaProducer::~KafkaProducer() (kafkaproducer.cpp:38)
==4627==    by 0x409DC0: KafkaProducerFactory::~KafkaProducerFactory() (kafkaproducerfactory.cpp:22)
==4627==    by 0x4045A8: main (test_kafkaproducerfactory.cpp:14)
```

kafkaproducer.cpp lines 56-67 (double-spacing preserved):

```
 if(m_producer)           // line 56
     delete m_producer;

 if(m_topic)
     delete m_topic;


 if(m_tconf)
     delete m_tconf;

 if(m_conf)
     delete m_conf;       // line 67
```

Any help is welcome.

**UPDATE**

I already found the following codes caused this problem. If I commented the following part (If I did not set the event call back function.), the problem would disappear. **But I have no idea why it caused the problem. I used the same way to set delivery call back function, which did not cause any problem.** It is wired.

```
//defination
    class MyEventCb : public RdKafka::EventCb
    {
    public:
        void event_cb (RdKafka::Event &event)
        {
        }
    private:

    };

//set the callback function
    if( m_conf->set("event_cb", &m_event_cb, m_errstr) != RdKafka::Conf::CONF_OK)
    {
        DBG_PRINT( 1, "Kafka::Failed to set event callback : %s\n", m_errstr.c_str() );
        return false;
    }
    // Class member
MyEventCb m_event_cb; // event callback
```

Comment: You do not have to explicitly check pointer for `nullptr` delete will handle that properly

Comment: Do you follow rule of 3? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: So your code is reading a 8-byte sized value (a pointer?) inside something that has been freed...

Comment: Please don't use the `>` quote mechanism to quote code or output from valgrind, etc.  It is harder to read than material indented as code.

Comment: I followed the example in https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/examples/rdkafka_example.cpp. But RdKafka::Conf *conf (new in line 175) was not deleted in main function. I am confused. I am not sure whether m_tconf is deleted twice.

Comment: Note that it is legitimate and safe to `delete` a null pointer; it does nothing.  So the checks aren't really necessary.

Comment: After freeing memory, the next call should always be to either assign new memory to that pointer variable or set it to NULL.  For thread-safe applications, be sure to use a critical section, lock, or mutex.

Comment: RdKafka  seem to be using your `m_conf` object after you have deleted it. Though It's hard to say what you should do to fix it, you link to some rdkafka_example.cpp, which doesn't seem to be the other code you've posted.

Comment: @nos, I followed rdkafka_example.cpp to create my own Kafka producer class. I am just confused by that RdKafka::Conf *conf was not deleted in this example. In my class, if I did not delete my own m_conf pointer, there would be memory leaks. Now I am looking into the source code of this library.

Comment: @JimFell I assigned NULL to delete pointer. But I did not post my remaining codes. Thanks. Also I recalled that coverity complained that the NULL checking before delete. Thanks all of you. But I am still stuck by the invalid read problem.

Comment: @ChengchengPei Likely you're deleting the conf object at the wrong point in time, perhaps something that keeps it around is not shut down before you're deleting it. At a guess, you can delete it after `RdKafka::wait_destroyed(5000);` , though it may be possible to do it earlier as well.

Comment: @nos I tried, but still the problem.

Comment: @ChengchengPei I think you are hitting this bug: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/issues/226   Are you using latest master?

Comment: @Edenhill I am using 0.8.6-1

Answer (score 1):

Since m_topic is using m_producer i don't think you should delete m_producer before m_topic...